# NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsNodeList.getLength()J at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsNodeList.append

Tags: coldfusion, itext, xmlworker

I'm having one of those "nothing has changed, but we changed a bunch of stuff" problems.

I haven't changed the source code.  We DID change servers.  When I try to use the FillandFlatten routine from itext xfaworker, I get the error at the bottom of this page.  We are running all 5.5.4 version files.  I get no errors/warnings when compiling.

I am importing the following (the last two were an attempt to fix this):

```
import com.allaire.cfx.*;
import com.itextpdf.license.LicenseKey;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.XfaForm;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.*;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsNodeList;
```

Although I am fairly certain that the fix is going to be something I did, I don't know where to look anymore.

ERROR GENERATED:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsNodeList.getLength()J at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.RhinoJsNodeList.append(RhinoJsNodeList.java:37) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsTree.addChild(JsTree.java:94) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsNode.addChild(JsNode.java:234) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.pipe.DataPipeline.open(DataPipeline.java:70) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:371) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.TagEncounteredState.process(TagEncounteredState.java:104) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:236) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:214) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:187) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:401) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:282) at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:253) at FillAndFlatten.manipulatePdf(FillAndFlatten.java:125) at FillAndFlatten.processRequest(FillAndFlatten.java:87)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check your dependency versions. NoSuchMethodError most often indicates that different versions than at compile time are used at run time, incompatible ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this problem before in the following context.

Suppose that you have an application A with a dependency on library B. You have two jars: A-1.0.jar and B-1.0.jar. A-1.0.jar is compiled using B-1.0.jar.

In version 1.0 of library B, there is a method `foo()` that returns `void`:

```
public void foo() { ... }
```

However, in version 2.0, this method is changed in the sense that it now returns `int`:

```
public int foo() { ... }
```

The *name* of the method didn't change, but its *signature* did.

Now you get a new jar: B-2.0.jar, but if you use A-1.0.jar with B-2.0.jar, you will get a `NoSuchMethodError` because the method `foo()` can not be found. In reality, the method `foo()` is still there, but version 1.0 of application A is looking for `public void foo()` whereas version 2.0 of library B doesn't know about such a method. It only knows about a method `public int foo()`.

The only way to solve problems like this, is to recompile application A with the new jar for B into A-2.0.jar. A-1.0.jar won't work with B-2.0.jar, but A-2.0.jar will (even if you didn't change anything to application A).

**DISCLAIMER:** this answer is based on the occurrence of a `NoSuchMethodError` in general. I haven't checked if this explains the specific problem with XFA Worker, but I see that a ticket has been method on the issue tracker at iText Software, which means that one of our engineers will check if my educated guess is correct (if not, that engineer will post an extra answer).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'm not sure EXACTLY what fixed it, but we did a few things.

1)  I emptied my lib directory and refilled it with the latest downloaded files.  This ensured that all of my jar files were up to date.

2)  Obviously, I recompiled everything after I completed this.

3)  I noticed that ColdFusion had a few updates pending.  I asked the CF manager to apply the updates.

It works now.

Comment: Configuration problems are always tricky. I don't know if my answer was "the" answer, but thank you for accepting the answer.